# Design and code a task scheduler that can take unsynchronized or synchronized tasks

Tags: java, task, synchronized

This is an interview question, that means this could be done in a short time.
I thought to ask here because I cannot figure out what to do if I were asked.

**"Design and code a task scheduler that can take unsynchronized or synchronized tasks"**

Please use your imagination/assumption and share your thoughts and comments.

Comment: What do you mean by synchronized tasks then? From a CPU scheduler standpoint it makes no sense to ask such a question as those are higher level synchronization primitives (mutex, condition variables, barriers, etc...)

Comment: This was asked during Google's interview http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Design-and-code-a-task-scheduler-that-can-take-unsynchronized-or-synchronized-tasks-QTN_410705.htm

Comment: Technically any scheduler can handle both, it's up to the person writing the tasks to handle the higher level primitives (unless you need real time or something like that).

Comment: Seems to me like Google's interview questions are getting worse since when I interviewed with them.

Comment: @JesusRamos - I disagree.  This question seems to be (in part) designed to see how you deal with vague and ambiguous requirements. And sorting out the technically feasible from the infeasible. Those are both important skills for a developer doing leading edge stuff.

Comment: @StephenC The problem is that this question spans too many problem spaces without further specifics. People who like Java will give Java answers, etc... It looks generic on the surface but to me it seems that most answers (as you can see below) will always be specific to some platform or language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is deliberately vague, it's suppose to show how good you are at designing and solving problems, what kind of assumptions do you make, how you justify them, etc. There is no single, good answer. It's a matter of approaching the problem.

That being said here is my take:

1. My scheduler can take arbitrary `Runnable` or `Callable<V>`, I will implement [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) because it seems to be a good abstraction for the problem. I am using as many standard classes as I can to make API portable and easy to use.
2. By *unsychronized* and *synchronized* I understand: safe to run concurrently and those that require exclusive lock. I.e. the scheduler is not allowed to run two *synchronized* tasks at the same time.
3. The distinction between synchronized and unsychronized tasks will be made using marker interface. Annotation is also fine, but harder to extract at runtime.
4. I won't give you the full implementation, but it'll probably wrap some standard `ScheduledExecutorService` with an additional synchronization for synchronized tasks. I think `ConcurrentMap<Class, Semaphore>` would do. Before running tasks marked as *synchronized* I make sure no other *synchronized* task of the same time is running. I block and wait or reject (this can be configurable).

Answer (score 0):

I would use an ExecutorService as it's built in and does most of the things you would want. It doesn't care if those tasks uses synchronized or not.